# Globaly replace all new operators

Tags: c++, new-operator

I'm using an RTOS in an (embedded) C++ application. Since i'm working on an embedded target i try to keep the heap allocations to a minimum. However at some point STL classes like vector come in very handy.

Because i'm using a RTOS, i have to make sure that the new/malloc() call is thread safe. Luckyly my RTOS (FreeRTOS) provides it's own (threadsafe) malloc() routines. I only do have to use them.

So far i implemented the following new/delete pair and linked it into the binary.

```
void * operator new(size_t n) noexcept(false);


void operator delete(void * p) noexcept(true);


void operator delete(void * p, size_t n) noexcept(true);
```

However looking at this

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

shows me a dozen overloads of new (and as many overloads for delete).
Do all new or delete overloads default to my replacement or am i missing an operator overload?

Comment: Each STL class which is allocating something provides a template parameter to specify the used allocator: `template<
    class T,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class vector;`

Comment: Why do you believe the standard allocation functions aren’t thread-safe?

Comment: You need to replace all overloads of operators `new` (and corresponding operator `delete`) that your program uses. You may get lucky, but there are no particular guarantees about one overload of operator `new` defaulting to calling another.Before worrying abouta thread-safe allocator/deallocator, I'd seriously look to see if the system can be designed to avoid allocating and deallocating on the fly (e.g. allocate during startup, before launching threads, and deallocate after all launched threads are complete) - even with thread safety, dynamic allocation and deallocation gives non-determinism

Comment: Usually, in embedded systems `operator new` is defined as just a call to `malloc` (in Arduino, for example, it's defined that way both `new` and `new[]`, which in turn makes safe but unportable to allocate with `new[]` and deallocate by mistake with `delete`). You should check what's going on **before** you implement your on calls.

Comment: unfortunately there's another problem. if i try to allocate a huge amount of data using the default new operator a hard fault is thrown. This was actually my main intension why i replaced the new operator. And yes on my embedded system new is just a call to malloc which is not thread safe. So basically you're saying that i cannot be sure which new operator the specific STL class is actually using? The Allocator type is alyways set to std::allocator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour of the standard library for many of the `operator new` and `operator delete` overloads is to forward to the "basic" versions of `operator new` and `operator delete`.

The "basic" operators are:

```
void* operator new (std::size_t count);
void* operator new (std::size_t count, std::align_val_t alignment); // C++17 only
void operator delete(void* ptr) noexcept;
void operator delete(void* ptr, std::align_val_t alignment) noexcept; // C++17 only
```

Assuming that you have a standard library implementation that implements the default behaviour as defined in the C++ standard¹, the above operators are the only ones that you need to replace.

The default behaviour was first defined in the C++11 standard, so your standard library implementation must support this at minimum.

[1]: See the section titled "Storage allocation and deallocation [new.delete]" in a C++ standard.